# Quarto: `.content-visible` and `AND` checking of multiple profiles

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

I would like to do something like:

```
::: {.content-visible when-profile="profileA"}
Some Content
:::
```

**BUT** checking for an `AND` combination of profile A & B, meaning that "Some Content" only is rendered when both `profileA` and `profileB` are active.

Both of these do not currently work:

1. Dual `when-profile` arguments:

   ```
   ::: {.content-visible when-profile="profileA" when-profile="profileB"}
   Some Content
   :::
   ```
2. Array of profiles:

   ```
   ::: {.content-visible when-profile=["profileA", "profileB"]}
   Some Content
   :::
   ```

Any ideas on how to do this more concisely then the working

```
:::: {.content-visible when-profile="profileA"}
::: {.content-visible when-profile="profileB"}
Some Content
:::
::::
```